# Problem in Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solution curves for the differential equations
1) y' = max{y,y^2}
2) y‘ = min {y,y^2}

Please can anybody help me because I am really confused

Answer (score 2):

Hints: On which region is $y > y^2$?  On which region is $y < y^2$?  Do you know what the solutions of $y' = y$ and $y' = y^2$ are?

Comment: Yes i know the answer to y‘=y is y(t)=e^t evaluated at y(0)=1 and for y'=y^2 we have y(t)=t+1 also evaluated at y(0)=1 but i need the maximal interval of existence. NB: domain is R^2

Comment: No. For $y'=y$ that's one solution, not the general solution.  For $y' = y^2$ it's completely wrong.

Comment: Why? Just explain further

Comment: Which part don't you understand?